# Why does this keep coming up when i try to run my program

Tags: python-3.x

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/sam/Downloads/Carsy045 (10).py", line 9, in

from playing_cards import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playing_cards'

Why does this message pop up when i try to run my code?!?

## File: Carsy045.py

## Author:

## Email Id:

## Description: Assignment 2 - Blackjack Game

## This is my own work as defined by the University's

## Academic Misconduct policy.

from playing_cards import *
def get_hit_choice():

"""

Ask the user whether to hit or stand. Makes sure

the user enters a valid choice

"""

choice = input("Please enter h or s (h = Hit, s = Stand): ")

while choice != "h" and choice != "s":

```
choice = input("Please enter h or s (h = Hit, s = Stand): ")
```

return choice

def get_play_choice(prompt_text):

"""

Display a prompt and forces the user to select yes or no

"""

choice = input(prompt_text)

while choice != "y" and choice != "n":

```
choice = input(prompt_text)
```

return choice

def get_hand_total(hand):

"""

Calculate the score of the hand

"""

total = 0

num_aces = 0

# Total the non-aces

for card in hand:

```
if card[0] == "A":

  # Separate aces

  num_aces += 1

elif card[0] in ["T", "J", "Q", "K"]:

  total += 10

else:

  total += int(card[0])
```

# Put in the aces such that it won't bust

# Aces is 1 or 11

for i in range(num_aces):

```
if total + 11 < 21:

  total += 11

else:

  total += 1
```

return total

def card_to_string(card):

"""

Return a string representation of a card

"""

card_str = card[0] + " of "

if card[1] == "S":

```
card_str += "Spades"
```

elif card[1] == "H":

```
card_str += "Hearts"
```

elif card[1] == "D":

```
card_str += "Diamonds"
```

elif card[1] == "C":

```
card_str += "Clubs"
```

return card_str

def display_hand(hand_text, hand):

"""

Display the list of hand to the console

"""

# Print the label

print(hand_text + " " + str(get_hand_total(hand)) + ": ", end="")

# Print the cards

for i in range(len(hand)):

```
print(card_to_string(hand[i]), end="")



if i + 1 < len(hand):

  print(" | ", end="")
```

print()

def play_player_hand(player_hand):

"""

Play the player hand until it goes bust

or user chooses to stand

"""

stand = False

# Keep going until user chooses to stand or have been busted

while get_hand_total(player_hand) < 21 and not stand:

```
choice = get_hit_choice()

print()



if choice == "s":

  # Stand is only applicable if the total sum is 15 or greater

  if get_hand_total(player_hand) < 15:

    print("Cannot stand on value less than 15!")

  else:

    stand = True

elif choice == "h":

  # Add a new card

  player_hand.append(deal_one_card())

  display_hand("Player's hand is", player_hand)

  print()
```

# Return the total score of the player's hand

return get_hand_total(player_hand)

def play_dealer_hand(dealer_hand):

"""

Play the dealer hand until it goes bust or it reached

the minimum required score

"""

display_hand("Dealer's hand is", dealer_hand)

while get_hand_total(dealer_hand) < 17:

```
dealer_hand.append(deal_one_card())

display_hand("Dealer's hand is", dealer_hand)
```

# Return the total score of the dealer's hand

return get_hand_total(dealer_hand)

def is_black_jack(hand):

"""

Check if the hand is a black jack

"""

return len(hand) == 2 and get_hand_total(hand) == 21

def get_card_value(card):

"""

Return the numeric value of a card

"""

if card[0] in ["J", "Q", "K", "T"]:

```
value = 10
```

elif card[0] == "A":

```
value = 1
```

else:

```
value = int(card[0])
```

return value

def play():

"""

Play a new round, returns the state whether the

user won, lost, or draw

"""

print("-------------------- START GAME --------------------")

# Deal 2 cards to the dealer and player

dealer_hand = [deal_one_card(), deal_one_card()]

player_hand = [deal_one_card(), deal_one_card()]

# Show only the first card of the dealer

print("Dealer's hand is " + str(get_card_value(dealer_hand[0])) + ": " + card_to_string(dealer_hand[0]))

display_hand("Player's hand is", player_hand)

print()

result = ""

# Do some initial evaluation for blackjack

if is_black_jack(dealer_hand) and is_black_jack(player_hand):

```
result = "draw"

print("*** Blackjack --")

display_hand("Dealer's hand is", dealer_hand)

display_hand("Player's hand is", player_hand)

print()

print("*** Blackjack! Push - no winners! ***")
```

elif is_black_jack(dealer_hand):

```
result = "dealer"

display_hand("Dealer's hand is", dealer_hand)

print()

print("*** Blackjack! Dealer Wins! ***")
```

elif is_black_jack(player_hand):

```
result = "player"

display_hand("Player's hand is", player_hand)

print()

print("*** Blackjack Player Wins! ***")
```

else:

```
# If nobody got blackjack, time to play each player

player_score = play_player_hand(player_hand)

if player_score > 21:

  print("--> Player busts!")

  print()



dealer_score = play_dealer_hand(dealer_hand)

if dealer_score > 21:

  print()

  print("--> Dealer busts!")



# Present the final score

print()

print("--- Dealer: " + str(dealer_score) + " Player: " + str(player_score) + " -> ", end="")



# Evaluate final winner

if (player_score > 21 and dealer_score > 21) or (player_score == dealer_score):

  result = "draw"

  print("Push - no winners!", end="")

elif player_score > dealer_score:

  result = "player"

  print("Player Wins!", end="")

else:

  result = "dealer"

  print("Dealer Wins!", end="")



print(" ---")
```

print("--------------------- END GAME ---------------------")

return result

def main():

"""

Entry point of the program that organizes the game and tallies

the results

"""

play_again = get_play_choice("Would you like to play BlackJack [y|n]? ")

print()

# Variables to keep track stats

won = 0

lost = 0

drawn = 0

# Keep playing as long as user wants to

while play_again == "y":

```
result = play()

print()



# Tally the result

if result == "player":

  won += 1

elif result == "dealer":

  lost += 1

else:

  drawn += 1



# Ask user if they want to play again

print("That was fun!")

print()



play_again = get_play_choice("Play again [y|n]? ")

print()
```

# Display the stats

print("You played " + str(won + lost + drawn) + " games!")

print(" -> Won: " + str(won))

print(" -> Lost: " + str(lost))

print(" -> Drawn: " + str(drawn))

print()

print("Thanks for playing! :)")

main()

Answer (score 0):

This message appears because you told the compiler to import a `playing_cards` module and the compiler could not find it.  This `import` statement is at the beginning of your script.  All the following voluminous code is irrelevant.

To stop getting this message, you need a Python file `playing_cards.py` in one of the directories where the compiler looks for modules.

It might help to review references on [how to write a module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-modules-in-python-3) and [where the compiler looks for modules](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/sys_path.html).